# How to set classpath for properties declared under property set in maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am working on converting from ant build tool to maven tool.
    Ant build.xml has initialized properties in below way

```
<property name="home.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="external.dir" value="${home.dir}/external"/>
```

and class path has been set in build.xml as below:

```
<target name="setClassPath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${external.dir}/log4j" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
</target>
```

Could you please help me how to add classpath in pom.xml?

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom classpath using `additionalClasspathElement` tag in `pom.xml`.

```
<additionalClasspathElement>${external.dir}/log4j</additionalClasspathElement>
```

Comment: why don't add log4j as dependency to the project? Does it make sense to work against the principle **convention over configuration**?

Comment: that is solution but @user asked specifically for setting up the class path.

Comment: of course he did, but he's a beginner with maven. So we should point out the maven principles

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui/@JimHawkins Which will be best way to follow is adding as dependency or additionalClasspathElement through sure fire plugin

Comment: my updated answer shows how to include the dependencies for `log4j`. For detailed informations about surefire plugin, you should create a new question. **one problem - one question** is the way this side works in general

Comment: @JimHawkins is right about convention over configuration thing. adding dependency will be good for `log4j`. i answered keeping `classPath` in mind which is correct also. go with adding dependency

Answer (score 2):

> Could you please help me how to add classpath in pom.xml?

Don't care about manually defining the classpath when using maven.
One of the most basic things you've to internalise when start learning Maven is: Maven follows the the concept **convention over configuration**

For the classpath this means, that every library (the maven term is dependency) which you add in the section `<dependencies>` of `pom.xml` is automatically part of the classpath.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.so</groupId>
    <artifactId>csvProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you need a config file or an image to be part of the classpath, put them in the `resources` folder of your project.

A typical starter Maven project looks like this:

```
csvProject
|   pom.xml
|
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   |   \---de
|   |   |       \---so
|   |   |               CsvExample.java
|   |   |
|   |   \---resources
|   |   |   \---images
|   |   |   |         logo.png
|   |   |   |   some.properties
|   |   |   \---de
|   |           \---so
|   |                   more.properties
|   \---test
|       \---java
```

For more informations look at[Maven home](http://maven.apache.org/) or use google to find a tutorial.