# How to force setup maven dependencies in java classpath?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, classpath

Is there a way to force maven dependencies in the `java` classpath? Here is the maven dependency file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suhail</groupId>
    <artifactId>JasperCSVDataSource</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>    

</project>
```

and my project structure looks as follows:

[image]

Although the maven dependencies were automatically installed by `VisualStudioCode`, they were not linked to the `java` classpath. Is there a way I could take care of this?

How do I make sure that the maven dependencies installed for the project get automatically linked to the java classpath?

Comment: Maven does set the classpath to the dependencies correctly, but not prefixed with repository location. Try adding 
`<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` tag, checkout here for more information: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Comment: @redshift This [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802837/how-to-set-classpath-for-properties-declared-under-property-set-in-maven) suggests that the classpath is automatically added. But it is not happening for me

Comment: did you try the second answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802837/how-to-set-classpath-for-properties-declared-under-property-set-in-maven)?

Comment: What is the output of `mvn dependency:build-classpath`?

Comment: @redshift Gives out `BUILD SUCCESS`

Comment: the console log must be showing information like `[INFO] Dependencies classpath:`, does it lists all the directories you need?